# Bijection between $V$ and $V^*$ the covector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read that there is no "natural" bijection between $V$ and $V^*$.

But if I take $V$ of finite dimension, if I have a vector :

$$ V=V^\mu e_\mu $$

I can associate to it a covector $v$ such as :

$$ v=V^\mu e^*_\mu $$

Where $e^*_\mu$ is the linear form defined as $e^*_\mu(e_\nu)=\delta_{\mu \nu}$.

Why don't we consider this bijection ?

Comment: You chose a basis; this is the "unnaturality" of the bijection. By contrast the inclusion from $V$ to $V^{**}$ can be taken "naturally" without reference to a basis.

Comment: Ah ok. When we want something natural we want to define it as independent of any choice of basis. Thank you

Comment: In fact I think there is some deeper categorical significance to the use of this word "natural" in this context, but I'm not familiar enough with category theory to provide details.